# Move outlook item to archive

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2013

I have a C# program (actually it's just a C# library that is being used by NUnit) that I wish to modify slightly which is based off of this article: [How to Programmatically move items in outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268996.aspx). I'm currently faced with a folder that has bout 3500 messages all around 350kb and is taking FOREVER to move to my archive so I can send and receive emails again (since my inbox is currently at 1.5Gb out of 500Mb... lol) but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get my archive folder. I'm a little bit multitasking since I'm at work so I can edit as I go. So if you have any code readily available that finds the archive folder that would be great. Thank you

**EDIT**

ok to show that I do have some work in progress (based on negative feedback) here is the code I have in place right now (since yes I know I have a give me teh codez)

here is my NUnit test case that looks at a folder and gives me specific information

```
    [Test]
    public void CheckMessages()
    {
        List<EmailMessage> messages = new List<EmailMessage>();
        using (var target = new EmailMessageProvider())
        {
            messages.AddRange(target.GetEmailMessages("UnexpectedErrors\\NotFindImage"));
        }

        Dictionary<int, string> asdf = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        foreach (var item in messages)
        {
            var line = item.Body.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)[2];

            var revisionId = int.Parse(Regex.Match(line, @"\-*\d+").Value);
            var path = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("\\\\"));
            if (asdf.ContainsKey(revisionId))
            {
                Assert.That(path, Is.EqualTo(asdf[revisionId]));
            }
            else
            {
                asdf.Add(revisionId, path);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in asdf.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} {item.Value}");
        }
    }
```

I use the same class to find messages (in another test) and move it to that subfolder which that test is using.

here is the code I have that does the moving

```
    public void MoveSurveyPrintComponentsNotFound()
    {
        var destination = _baseFolder.Folders["UnexpectedErrors"].Folders["NotFindImage"];
        foreach (var mailItem in _baseFolder.Folders["UnexpectedErrors"].Items.OfType<MailItem>())
        {
            mailItem.UseMailItem(x =>
            {
                if (x.Body.Contains("Foobar.Common.Exceptions.ImageNotFound"))
                    x.Move(destination);
            });
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

looks like I may have just about got it. I found that in the `MAPI Namspace` one of the subfolders is Archives. I'm going to try to change a few of the variables and see if it moves. Problem is just checking one folder takes over 31 seconds. oh well. better than never.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. It wasn't as hard as I had thought either so I'll share what i have just incase someone else has this problem. In my program I did 2 things. One was to set `_basefolder` as my default email address's Folder. Second was to to set `_mapi` to the `Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")`. Those two thinsg I already had in my constructor.

```
    private readonly OutlookApplication _outlook;
    private readonly NameSpace _mapi;
    private MAPIFolder _baseFolder;

    public EmailMessageProvider()
    {
        _outlook = new OutlookApplication();
        _mapi = _outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        _baseFolder = _mapi.Folders["robert@defaultEmail.com"];
    }
```

Archives works just like any other MAPIFolder so it's just a matter of getting said folder. For me it was in `_mapi.Folders["Archive"]`. I would imagine this is fairly standard so if you copy and paste it should work just fine.

So now to list out all of my emails I want to go through and move tham appropriatly.

```
    public void MoveSpecificEmailsToArchives()
    {
        var destination = _mapi.Folders["Archives"];
        foreach (var mailItem in _baseFolder.Folders["Unexpected Error"].Items.OfType<MailItem>())
        {
            mailItem.UseMailItem(x =>
            {
                if (x.Body.Contains("offensiveProgram.exe ERROR "))
                    x.Move(destination);
            });
        }
        Release(destination);
    }
```

fyi the `UseMailItem` is an extension method. Looks like this

```
    public static void UseMailItem(this MailItem item, Action<MailItem> mailItemAction)
    {
        mailItemAction(item);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
    }
```